# Why mongoose Model object returned got a _id property, but id works as well in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, mongoose

I  was using Typescript to get an object

```js
const query = Workflow.where({ _id: id });
const workflow = await query.findOne().exec();
console.log(workflow); // <-- (1) this console.log()
console.log(workflow.id); // <-- (2) this console.log()
return workflow;
```

Then I got:

```js
{
  _id: 608e7fb7ee267e23fff1da65,
  title: 'WorkFlow 14',
  description: 'Este es un nuevo workflow',
  date: 2021-05-02T10:32:23.423Z,
  __v: 0
}
608e7fb7ee267e23fff1da65
```

As you note I got `_id` as property in first console.log but the when I console.log `workflow.id` I get the result.

My Schema

```js
import mongoose from 'mongoose';

const WorkflowSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  title: { type: String, required: true },
  description: { type: String, required: false },
  date: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
});

export default mongoose.model('Workflow', WorkflowSchema);
```

This happens only with id property.

Why did it works? I expected an Error or an `undefined` at least.

Comment: Maybe there is some alias or typescript feature?

Answer (score 3):

`id` is string version of `_id` and this getter exists on all documents by default.

More info [here](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api/document.html#document_Document-id).

Answer (score 1):

This is a feature of Mongoose. So it is not happening because you are using TypeScript, it would also happen if you did it in JavaScript.

> Mongoose assigns each of your schemas an id virtual getter by default
> which returns the document's _id field cast to a string, or in the
> case of ObjectIds, its hexString.